# PHP/MySQL issues when running WP on EC2 cloud

Tags: php, mysql, amazon, cloud

I am trying to create a wordpress blog on an Amazon EC2 instance. The amazon base image had apache and php already installed. I installed MySQL manually in my user directory. I am able to login to the MySQL database from linux command line. But I am not able to connect to the MySQL db from php. The scenario I tested was the following. I have a php file which I host through apache. When I open that php file in a browser; the MySQL connection fails. The following is the message in the browser

```
Error establishing a database connection

This either means that the username and password information in your wp-config.php file is incorrect or we can't contact the database server at xxx.xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com:port. This could mean your host's database server is down.

    Are you sure you have the correct username and password?
    Are you sure that you have typed the correct hostname?
    Are you sure that the database server is running?
```

My question is. Is it incorrect to manually install MySQL when php has already been installed? I mean is it recommended to compile-install the php with mysql first?

**EDIT**

php/apache was already pre-installed in the machine which I instantiated from amazon. It has amazon linux as the OS.

```
rpm -qa |grep -i httpd
httpd-tools-2.2.16-1.0.amzn1.x86_64
httpd-2.2.16-1.0.amzn1.x86_64

rpm -qa |grep -i php
php-common-5.3.5-1.11.13.amzn1.x86_64
php-5.3.5-1.11.13.amzn1.x86_64
php-cli-5.3.5-1.11.13.amzn1.x86_64
```

Thanks. The yum install mysql-server helped a bit. So first I removed my manual installation; and then yum install mysql-server; Additionally yum install -y php php-mysql

**EDIT 2**

I debugged a bit more. What I found is that if I put the wordpress directory under apache root and don't do port forwarding (no Proxy and proxyreverse), then I am able to connect to the DB from the WP install files. However, if I put the WP files under JBoss and do port forwarding from apache to JBoss, then from within JBoss, I am unable to connect through WP php files to the MySQL DB. So the problem is somewhere within the Caucho Quercus part of JBoss. Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: How did you install PHP/Apache, What distribution of Linux?

Comment: php/apache was already pre-installed in the machine which I instantiated from amazon. It has amazon linux as the OS.

Comment: You should have just typed `yum install mysql-server` to install MySQL from Amazon's package repository. If it's working, though, it doesn't matter how you did it. If you can connect to the server with the `mysql` CLI, then so can your code once you figure out what mistake you made there.

Comment: Better suited for [Server Fault](http://www.serverfault.com).

Comment: Is there a reason why you didn't want to just use Amazon's WordPress template for this? Just curious.

Comment: This is a **PHP/MySQL/Apache install/configuration** question, not a **WordPress** question.

Comment: When I was selecting my EC2 instance (about a 8 months back), I didn't have a good choice there. I mean, either it was

1. The EC2 template instances that amazon themselves provide (not third party templates), didn't have wordpress support.

OR

2. The EC2 Wordpress template didn't have the other stuff I needed (apache, tomcat); by default.

I forget which was the reason.

Answer (score 0):

Try logging into the mysql instance from the command line by typing in `mysql -u root -p` and then entering your mysql root password. If you can connect, even if it rejects your username and password, you know it's up and running correctly.

From that point you can diagnose whether it is username/password issues or whether or not you need to properly [configure mysql.ini](http://www.google.com/#hl=en&xhr=t&q=configure+mysql)

Comment: Thanks. I debugged a bit more. What I found is that if I put the wordpress directory under apache root and don't do port forwarding (no Proxy and proxyreverse), then I am able to connect to the DB from the WP install files. However, if I put the WP files under JBoss and do port forwarding from apache to JBoss, then from within JBoss, I am unable to connect through WP php files to the MySQL DB. So the problem is somewhere within the Caucho Quercus part of JBoss. Any suggestions? Thanks